# Plone portal transforms outdated?

Tags: plone, css

I want to have a custom text transformer in Plone, but when I started to read  [documentation](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/portal-transforms) I realized that the document is for

> an unsupported version of Plone, Plone 2.1.x

which is far away from the edge. Here is my question:

Is portal transforms really outdated or old technology. If so, what's the successor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`portal_transforms` is still in use in Plone 4.2. Attempts have been made to modernize it, but nothing as yet has replaced it.

Comment: Roger that. So, I'll go with this manual and source code studies. Thanks a lot.